# Negative power in bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, quantum-states

While reading for example Nuclear Collective Motion by Rowe, or other materials, I've encountered the notation,

$$\langle m (i)^{-1} | V | n (j)^{-1} \rangle ,$$

where $m, n, i, j$ are particle and hole states respectively.

I've also found this negative power in an article by Ring, Bauer and Speth, as,

$$\sum_{\lambda_3, \lambda_4} \langle\lambda_1 \lambda_2^{-1} L| F |\lambda_3 \lambda_4^{-1} L\rangle .$$

What might the -1 power signify here?

Comment: They use negative powers so that they do not use fractions. The power of -1 applies to the eigenvalue of a certain observable.

Comment: So in other words if $A|u> = a_u |u>$ then $A|u^{-1}> = \frac{1}{a_u} |u^{-1}>$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $|(a)^{-1} \,  b \, \rangle$ is just semantics to indicate a particle-hole state of a nucleus where "a particle is lifted from a single-particle state $a$ to the single-particle state $b$".

You may deliver the same concept with the symbol, say, $|a \rightarrow  b \, \rangle$... to give the intuitive idea that the particle in $a$ now is in $b$ (hence, there is a "hole" in $a$ and a "particle" in $b$). The "negative power" has no algebraic meaning in this context.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but are you certain about this? The information I've been seeing is starting to make me believe that 
$|u^{-1} \rangle = \langle u | $ 
or something like that. 
This is because for example in the book I read, Nuclear Collective Motion, it says at page 261 that $\langle a b^{-1} | V | c d^{-1} \rangle = \langle a d | V | b c \rangle$  and $\langle a b^{-1} c d^{-1} | V | \, \rangle = \langle a c | V | b d \rangle$

Comment: Yes I am sure, and Rowe himself gives this definition. If you are familiar with the creation and destruction operators I think that the relations that you are writing are a consequence of the fact that creating a particle in the bra is mathematically like creating a hole in the ket and vice versa.